# Android 4.4.2 external SD card mount paths and Titanium Backup

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, backup, external-sd, titanium-backup

I am about to wipe the stock ROM from my LG G3 and put in Resurrection Remix to get 5.1.1. My current stock ROM runs 4.4.2 of Android. In prep I downloaded the GApps and ROM zip files to "/storage/external_SD". I see them in there just fine.

I also told my Titanium Backup program to backup everything in the system for good measure. It seems to only backup to "/storage/emulated/legacy/TitaniumBackup". That is fine except I want to be completely sure this is going to the external SD card before I go wiping anything.

From what I have read it seems like "/storage/emulated/legacy" may be going to the external SD card. However that is a bit unclear.

Are there simply two partitions on the external SD card? Are both of those paths on the SD card? Is there an easy way to tell?

Comment: I'd expect everything in `/storage/emulated` rather to point to the *internal* card (see: [/storage/emulated/legacy/ vs /storage/emulated/0/ vs data/data/myApp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23625104/2533433)). `/storage/emulated/legacy` usually is a symlink; check where it's pointing to (`ls -l` in a terminal or via `adb shell`) and what's mounted there ( `mount`) to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most phones, `/storage/emulated/legacy`, `/storage/sdcard0`, `/sdcard`   points to the internal memory rather than the external SD card (but if you want to be completely sure, open up a [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and type the `mount` command with no arguments).

[Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) does allow changing the backup path though.

1. Open the app → press the Menu button and select **Preferences ...**.
2. Scroll down to find the **Backup folder location** option and select it.
3. In the popup, tap on **Storage provider** and select **Filesystem storage - Ext. SD card** -- this will display the contents of your external SD card
4. Select a folder to choose as your backup location, or choose **Use the current folder** to make **Titanium Backup** save backups onto the root directory of your card.